# Ideas for Rotation of AES Encryption Keys

Tags: apex, encryption

We are currently using AES 256 encryption with the Apex Crypto class. I need to implement a solution for key rotation. They keys themselves are stored in  protected custom metadata in a managed package.

Rotation seems tricky because it is a symmetric system and different parties would need to change keys at the same time or the system breaks. I have implemented a solution here that would support parallel keys for set period of time.

If the current key fails and we are still in the window then try the outgoing key.

But this does mean that in SF would would start using the new Encryption key the moment the package was installed. The biggest challenge here is working with external parties to add some sort of system like this.

Love to hear any suggestions about how others have worked with this issue in the past.

Here is some proof on concept code that I wrote today to test this.

````
 public class RotationDemoException extends Exception {}
    public  String CURRENT_KEY = 'Current_Key'; // Stores the developer name of the current active encryption key
    public  String OUTGOING_KEY = 'Retired_Key';
    

    global String encrypt(String stringToEncrypt) {
      Encryption_Key__mdt crytoMDT = Encryption_Key__mdt.getInstance(CURRENT_KEY);
        String keyString = crytoMDT.Key__c;
        System.debug(keyString);
        System.debug(keyString.length());
        Blob key = Blob.valueOf(keyString);

        Blob convertedString = Blob.valueOf(stringToEncrypt);
        Blob encryptedString = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, convertedString);
        String b64String = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedString);
        return b64String;
    }

    global  String decrypt(String stringToDecrypt) {
       Map<String, Encryption_Key__mdt> encryptionKeyMap = Encryption_Key__mdt.getAll();
        Blob valueToDecrypt = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(stringToDecrypt);
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();
        DateTime overlapEndTime = currentTime.addMinutes(Integer.valueOf(encryptionKeyMap.get(CURRENT_KEY).OverLap_Duration__c)); //set to  N number of minutes. 
        System.debug('overlapEndTime: ' + overlapEndTime);
       try {
           Blob key = Blob.valueOf(encryptionKeyMap.get(CURRENT_KEY).Key__c);
           Blob decryptedValue = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, valueToDecrypt);
           return decryptedValue.toString();

       }catch(System.SecurityException e){ //thrown when the key is not valid
         //if the validity date on the outgoing key is greater than the current time + the off set
         // throw an exception
           Encryption_Key__mdt outgoingKey = encryptionKeyMap.get(OUTGOING_KEY);
           Blob key = Blob.valueOf(outgoingKey.Key__c);
           System.debug('Created_Date__c: ' + encryptionKeyMap.get(OUTGOING_KEY).Validity_Date__c);
           if (outgoingKey.Validity_Date__c < overlapEndTime) {
               throw new RotationDemoException('Decryption failed with both old and new keys.');
           }

           Blob decryptedValue = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, valueToDecrypt);
           return decryptedValue.toString();
       }
    ```
````

Comment: This is a more complex problem then it might appear. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/79812/key-rotation-aes is a good summary, its last sentence _Sloppy key rotation only adds more opportunity for data to be exposed_ is a fair warning.